# Saving data even the app is close

Tags: android

hello guys I need your help I need to save progress data in my app . I created an App for letter tracing and I want to save the progress of the which letter is done tracing . like the color of image will be change if the letter is done tracing. or it will have star and when the app is close I want the progress is still there and not to start all over again. please help me guys this the screenshots of my app.

[image: Image that I want to change when the letter is done tracing]

[image: TracingView]

[image: SampleTracing]

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0):

When user swipes the finger on the screen you get (x,y) points of the touch events, so you can save the array of the (x,y) points the moment the user lifts his finger of the screen. As there may be a lot of points to save, you can decrease data by saving every second or third point in the array. Doing so will decrease the data you will work with but it also decrease the precision of the user line.